# ِAndroid class to handle MarshMallowPermission

Tags: java, android, authorization

Here is my class that handle all MarshMallow Permissions I prefer separate it class as I will call its methods in all my apps.

At  first I get used to check permission by this way:

```
private void CheckPermissionGranted() {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, CHECK_PERMISSION_CODE);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my class to handle all permissions:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by mina on 10/9/2016.
 */

public class MarshMallowPermission {

    public static final int RECORD_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    public static final int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
    public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 4;
    Activity activity;

    public MarshMallowPermission(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public boolean checkPermissionForRecord(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissionForWriteExternalStorage(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean checkPermissionForReadExternalStorage(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissionForCamera(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void requestPermissionForRecord(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Microphone permission needed for recording. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},RECORD_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public void requestPermissionForWriteExternalStorage(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
    public void requestPermissionForReadExternalStorage(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public void requestPermissionForCamera(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Camera permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

I check permission when use click button to upload Image from Camera or image library

```
private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {str_camera, str_image_lib,
            str_cancel};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UploadActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Files!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals(str_camera)) {
                if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForCamera()) {
                    marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForCamera();
                    return;
                }
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            } else if (items[item].equals(str_image_lib)) {
                if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForReadExternalStorage()) {
                    marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForReadExternalStorage();
                    return;
                }
                enableBrowseFile();
            } else if (items[item].equals(str_cancel)) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

if permission not granted I request permission , if granted I call methods that required this permission to run

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MarshMallowPermission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                enableBrowseFile();
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForReadExternalStorage();
                }
            }

            break;
        case MarshMallowPermission.CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForCamera();
                }
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

> ```
> public static final int RECORD_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
> public static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
> public static final int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
> public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 4;
> ```

This is a collection of compile-time constant expressions. You associate those to "magic" int-values. Instead of that an `enum` would provide type-safe request codes. For interoperability purposes with the Android API, you can expose a method `requestCode()`:

```
public enum RequestCode {
    Record(1), WriteExternalStorage(2), ReadExternalStorage(3), Camera(4);

    private final int code;
    private RequestCode(int code){
        this.code = code;
    }
    public int requestCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

This makes your code a tad easier to read IMO. Also it provides proper encapsulation instead of relying on constant class members.

---

Your `checkPermissionFor*()` methods all follow a certain pattern. You can drastically collapse these methods. The first step is seeing that the following code samples are equivalent:

> ```
> if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>     return true;
> } else {
>     return false;
> }
> ```

```
return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

The next step is seing the fact that you're "computing" result in always the same way. The only difference is the `Manifest.permission` you pass to `checkSelfPermission`. You can further simplify by using `import static` like the following:

```
import static android.support.v3.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission;
import static android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
import static android.Manifest.permission;

// ...
public boolean checkPermissionForRecord() {
    return checkSelfPermission(activity, permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

And suddenly the information benefit that your method provides vanished. The only real gain remaining from encapsulating this is now the fact that you provide a thin abstraction layer.

IMO that's not sufficient justification for that class to exist, at least not with the given usage code. If you use this in more than a handful of places it might be useful, but right now this class seems like it's useless baggage to me.